# What is the purpose of the UID within this Django Sign Up Function

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am learning how to create a django sign up page and I am at the point of creating an email verification. I am trying to use the code snippet here:

```
def usersignup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserSignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            email_subject = 'Activate Your Account'
            message = render_to_string('activate_account.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(email_subject, message, to=[to_email])
            email.send()
            return HttpResponse('We have sent you an email, please confirm your email
```

but I do not know what purpose the uid serves. Why is encoding the user model object in the verification email necessary?

Comment: The primary key can be a non-integer thing, like a `string`, `bytes`, etc. So it encoded in a base64 encoding.

Comment: If the user later validates their account, Django will need to activate the user. In order to do that, it needs to know *what* user to activate. The token only contains a hashed form of the primary key together with the timestamp, etc.